# Get file content acitivity on a Logic App in Azure

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm running issues with an Azure's Logic App activity. I've got a 'for each' activity which is checking and copying some files (Excel) from a source into a blob storage. Now in the path (URL) where the files (Excel) are locate there is also a Folder which is giving me trouble in the 'for each' activity. Before the folder was created, the files were alone inside that path. Once this new folder was created, the for each activity is erroring out reading the 'folder' and succeding in the Excel files. I now it can be solved just moving the folder out or the files into a different path but the source is managed by a different team. I'd like to know if there is some kind of filter that allow me just to pick the files (Excel)and skipping the existing Folder in the source path. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Get file content` you can use `Get file content using path`.

`Get file content` gives the file content using the file **identifier**. The contents can be copied somewhere else or be used as an attachment.

But in `Get file content using path` gives the file **contents using the path**.

So, It’s Get file content using path we get the file only it cannot identify the folder.

Refer [here for sharepoint actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#actions)